# Webcam not working on Dell Latitude 7400 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, dell, webcam, realtek

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Dell Latitude 7400.
The integrated webcam does not work.
Is there anything i can do to fix it?

lsusb -v output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5538 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x5538 
...
```

dmesg output:

```
~$ dmesg | grep uvcvideo
[   16.263344] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0bda:5538)
[   16.272214] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Realtek Extended Controls Unit was not initialized!
[   16.272215] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[   16.272216] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
[   16.272217] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   16.272218] uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   16.305653] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Comment: which program do you use?

Comment: I tried "cheese" from standard software and browser by visiting sites like webcamtests.com